# get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-name') always returns empty string

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I need to duplicate a list of thumbnails elsewhere on a page and have set up a few different custom thumbnail sizes in my functions.php file.

If I use:

```
the_post_thumbnail('photo-small');
```

Then the thumbnail gets displayed correctly, if I use:

```
echo get_post_thumbnail('photo-small');
```

Nothing gets echoed - it's an empty string.

What I am trying to do is add the generated img tags to an array so that I can loop through it outside of the loop but for some reason it's always blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `get_the_post_thumbnail()` and not the nonexistent `get_post_thumbnail()` function, right?

As JohnG said, you *have* to pass the ID of the current post to `get_the_post_thumbnail()` (the `the_post_thumbnail()` function already handles that for you). The [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) in the WordPress Codex has many usage examples:

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($id);                  // without parameter -> Thumbnail

get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'thumbnail');     // Thumbnail
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'medium');        // Medium resolution
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, 'large');         // Large resolution

get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(100,100) ); // Other resolutions
```

Where `$id` is the ID of the current post. You can get it via `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: Yep, that was it. What threw me was that the codex says the passing the id is optional at the top where it lists parameters; I misunderstood JohnG's response - it sounded like I only needed to include the ID if it was outside of the loop. Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1):

dumb question, but are you calling `the_post_thumbnail` from within a loop? If not, then you would want to use `get_post_thumbnail()`, but you'd need to pass in the `post_id` you want the featured image for

Comment: Yeah I am, I have it set up in the loops so that the_post_thumbnail('photo-small') is exectued which displays the image, but then in the same loop I add $images[] = get_the_post_thumbnail('photo-large'). the_post_thumbnail('photo-large') successfully echoes it. Makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `null` for id as long as it is in a loop.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'large' );
```